# Set visibility on Google Photos

Tags: privacy, google-photos

How do I set the visibility of my photos in Google Photos?

According to my dashboard there are 1,752 public photos in my Google Photos account. When I follow [this help page's advice](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6231876?hl=en&ref_topic=6128855) I see that I have a single album with 106 photo's shared with a few friends.
Has it something to do with pictures that were previously on Picasa maybe?

I would like to see a listing of the photos that are publicly available and I would like to set the visibility, preferably all of them at once.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a walkthrough on how to see your shared photos and stop sharing them taken from [Google Help](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6231876?hl=en&ref_topic=6128855). This might be different than public photos though.

To see your shared photos:

> 1. Open the Google Photos app or go to photos.google.com on a computer.
> 2. At the top left, touch or click the menu icon.
> 3. Select Shared links.

To stop sharing them:

> 1. Find the link you want to delete and click "Delete link".

Comment: Thanks for that, but it only shows that I linked an album with 106 photo's on google plus with a few select friends. This contradicts the data from my dashboard.

Comment: Also, check your Google + photos. There may be some that it's counting from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to photos.google.com on a computer, and just stay on the photos tab (ie don't go into Collections), how many photos can you see?

I recently discovered that there are some photos in your account that the Google Photos software doesn't show you - I think that this is something to do with the privacy settings on the tools where you uploaded them (eg via Blogger and Google Hangouts).     To see these photos, you need to use the [Picasa-web-albums software](https://picasaweb.google.com/home).   This organises photos by album, and I think you can only set permissions album-by-album, not overall.

Comment: Can't say how many there are (there's no count as far as I can tell), but there are several thousands. Up to way back to 2007 apparently.
I hoped the photos.google site would finally bring together the mess that is picasa and google+ and webalbums